# JVx DataBook readonly except one (few) columns

Tags: java, jvx

I have a standard RemoteDataBook in my screen. It has 30 columns and only 3 should be editable. I know that it's possible to set the UITable to readonly:

table.setEditable(false);

But how to make 3 columns editable, because all columns are readonly with editable(false).

I found a code snippet in the documentation:

`rdbContacts.getRowDefinition().getColumnDefinition("FILENAME").setReadOnly(true);`

but I have 30 columns... and is there a method like `setEditable(true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework doesn't offer setEditable(true), but it's easily possible to set only 3 columns editable, just do:

```
book.getRowDefinition().
     setReadOnly(ArrayUtil.removeAll(book.getRowDefinition().getColumnNames(), 
                                     new String[] {"A", "B", "C"}));
```

Another solution:

```
book.getRowDefinition().setReadOnly(null);
book.getRowDefinition().getColumnDefinition("A").setReadOnly(false);
book.getRowDefinition().getColumnDefinition("B").setReadOnly(false);
book.getRowDefinition().getColumnDefinition("C").setReadOnly(false);
```